# performance having joins with slick

Tags: playframework, slick

I was using play with anorm before.

recently i have migrated to use slick with play.

In my query i have joins between 4 tables.

The same joins with the query i gave in anorm is returning results faster than the slick.

Not sure why Slick seems to be too slow relative to anorm.

Is the there any location where i can see the queries generated by slick ?

using play 2.1.0 and https://github.com/freekh/play-slick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the generated SQL queries with `.selectStatement` on a Slick query.
This is [very briefly](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/lifted-embedding.html?highlight=selectstatement#querying) mentioned on the documentation.